# Firebase onDisconnect not called

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I was trying to cut down some active connection on my app. So I wanted to get disconnected from the `firebase` database when app is in the background.

So my `MainActivity` is the launcher activity. All other activities started from this activity are started on top of it. And `MainActivity` never get destroyed when a new activity is launched. So, I put a very simple logic to connect and disconnect from the `Firebase Database` like shown below:

In my Application's onCreate:

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    ...
    // Check for the connection state
    final DatabaseReference presenceRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("testing");
    // Write a string when this client loses connection
    presenceRef.onDisconnect().setValue("Disconnected");
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(".info/connected").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.getValue(Boolean.class)) {
                Log.v(TAG, "I am just connected");
                presenceRef.setValue("Connected");
            }
            else {
                Log.v(TAG, "I am just disconnected");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.v(TAG, "database connection error: " + databaseError.getMessage());
        }
    });
    ..
}
```

And my connection and disconnection logic is set in `MainActivity` like this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().goOnline();
    ...
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().goOffline();
    Toast.makeText(mContext, "Disconnecting", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

If press back button on `MainActivity`, db get disconnected. But, if I press home button, it is not disconnected that I understand as `onDestroy` will not be called.

But when I go to recent and swipe away my app, I can still see "Connected" at the testing location. I read somewhere that the `onDisconnect` is registered at the server end. So, if server sees a client disconnected, it should call `onDisconnected` function.

Isn't this unexpected behavior?

Comment: How long did you wait? When there is a "hard disconnect", the process disappears without giving the Firebase client a chance to signal to the server that it is closing the connection. In that case the server will detect the disconnect when the socket times out which may take a few minutes.

Comment: I have waited almost 10 minutes. And still it shows connected. I think its more than 10 minutes now.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen What's the socket timeout?

Comment: Its been more than an hour now! Still onDisconnect not called